# best way in java to rename a file , there are about 500 files in a directory

Tags: java, file-rename

I have 500 pdf files in a directory. I want to remove first five characters of a filename and rename it.

Comment: The best way would be to not use Java for this but bash or a scripting language.

Comment: would this solve the purpose ... NO JAVA btw ...................... dir /B > fileList.txt
for /f "tokens=1,2,3" %i in (fileList.txt) DO ren "%i %j %l" %l

Answer (score 22):

Sample code for you to rename the List of files in a given directory. In the below example, `c:\Projects\sample` is the folder, the files which are listed under that have been renamed to 0.txt, 1.txt, 2.txt, etc.

I hope this will solve your problem

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;

public class FileOps {


    public static void main(String[] argv) throws IOException {

        File folder = new File("\\Projects\\sample");
        File[] listOfFiles = folder.listFiles();

        for (int i = 0; i < listOfFiles.length; i++) {

            if (listOfFiles[i].isFile()) {

                File f = new File("c:\\Projects\\sample\\"+listOfFiles[i].getName()); 

                f.renameTo(new File("c:\\Projects\\sample\\"+i+".txt"));
            }
        }

        System.out.println("conversion is done");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 13):

something like this should do (Windows version):

```
import java.io.*;

public class RenameFile {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // change file names in 'Directory':
        String absolutePath = "C:\\Dropbox\\java\\Directory";
        File dir = new File(absolutePath);
        File[] filesInDir = dir.listFiles();
        int i = 0;
        for(File file:filesInDir) {
            i++;
            String name = file.getName();
            String newName = "my_file_" + i + ".pdf";
            String newPath = absolutePath + "\\" + newName;
            file.renameTo(new File(newPath));
            System.out.println(name + " changed to " + newName);
        }
    } // close main()
} // close class
```

Answer (score 4):

Use `File.listFiles(...)` to list the files in the directory, `String.substring(...)` to form the new file names, and `File.rename(...)` to do the renaming.

But I suggest that you have your application check that it can rename all of the files without any collisions *before you start the renaming*.

But @Pascal's comment is spot on.  Java is not the simplest tool for doing this kind of thing.

Answer (score 1):

As in your requirement, using java can achieve this like follows,

```
//path to folder location
String filePath = "C:\\CMS\\TEST";

//create direcotory TEST
File fileDir = new File(filePath);

if (!fileDir.exists()) {
   fileDir.mkdirs();
}

//create two file named 12345MyFile1.pdf, 12345MyFile2.pdf
File file1 = new File(filePath, "\\12345MyFile1.pdf");
file1.createNewFile();
File file2 = new File(filePath, "\\12345MyFile2.pdf");
file2.createNewFile();

//rename the file
File file = new File(filePath);
String[] fileList = file.list();//get file list in the folder

for (String existFileName : fileList) {
   String newFileName = existFileName.substring(5);//remove first 5 characters

   File sourceFile = new File(filePath + File.separator + existFileName);
   File destFile = new File(filePath + File.separator + newFileName);

   if (sourceFile.renameTo(destFile)) {
       System.out.println("File renamed successfully from: " + existFileName + " to: " + newFileName);
   } else {
       System.out.println("Failed to rename file");
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Java is a bad choice for this kind of work. A much better choice would be a JVM scripting language like Groovy. If you want to pursue this option

**Step 1:**

Download and install Groovy

**Step 2:**

Start the groovy console

**Step 3:**

Run this script

```
def dirName = "/path/to/pdf/dir"

new File(dirName).eachFile() { file -> 
    def newName = file.getName()[5..-1]
    File renamedFile = new File(dirName + "/" + newName)
    file.renameTo(renamedFile)

    println file.getName() + " -> " + renamedFile.getName() 
}
```

I'm assuming here that all the files are in the directory `/path/to/pdf/dir`. If some of them are in subdirectories of this directory, then use `File.eachFileRecurse` instead of `File.eachFile`.

Comment: +1 because I don't think this answer deserves 3 downvotes, especially without any explanation.

Comment: Could you please justify your point of view? It really depends on what he's looking for. If he wants a GUI based application, Java would be OK.

Comment: @SPI I'm assuming (perhaps incorrectly) that this is a once-off task

Comment: +1 since your solution is probably the most apt if this is a one off task!

Comment: it's better to go ahead with java program or command prompt, their no need download extra things...

Answer (score 0):

If you're on Windows you should use the command prompt or a .bat file. Windows supports wildcard renames natively at the OS level so it will be orders of magnitude faster than Java, which has to iterate over all the names and issue rename calls for each one.

Answer (score 0):

If you're on MacOS X and want to rename all files inside folders and subfolder from an External Drive, the code below will do the job:

```
public class FileOps {

    public static void main(String[] argv) throws IOException {
        String path = "/Volumes/FAT32/direito_administrativo/";
        File folder = new File(path);
        changeFilesOfFolder(folder);
    }

    public static void changeFilesOfFolder(File folder) {
        File[] listOfFiles = folder.listFiles();

        if (listOfFiles != null) {
            int count = 1;
            for (int i = 0; i < listOfFiles.length; i++) {
                if (listOfFiles[i].isFile()) {
                    File f = new File(folder.getPath() + "/" + listOfFiles[i].getName()); 
                    f.renameTo(new File(folder.getPath() + "/" + count + ".flv"));
                    count++;                    
                } else if (listOfFiles[i].isDirectory()) {
                    changeFilesOfFolder(listOfFiles[i]);
                }
            }
        } else {
            System.out.println("Path without files");
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This will change all the file names of the folders you mentioned:

```
for (int i = 0; i < folders.length; i++) {
    File folder = new File("/home/praveenr/Desktop/TestImages/" + folders[i]);
    File[] files2 = folder.listFiles();

    int count = 1;
    for (int j = 0; j <files2.length; j++,count++) {
        System.out.println("Old File Name:" + files2[j].getName());
        String newFileName = "/home/praveenr/Desktop/TestImages/" + folders[i]+"/file_"+count+"_original.jpg";
        System.out.println("New FileName:" + newFileName);
        files2[j].renameTo(new File(newFileName));
    }

}
```